# Wrong Source Path for Textures

Tags: texturing, path

I've tried using RebusFarm and it messed up all my Source Paths for my textures.

In the file i'm working in now all the textures are correct (There is no pink one) but when i try to pack all into blend file it gives me this message
[image: Source Path Error]

Does someone know how i can tell blender to take the right paths instead of this wrong one ?

Thank you!